# PDF based on employee_id

Tags: fpdf

NEED HELP!!!! :(

I have to finish a task in our project, lets say for example employees table has columns employee_id, username and password...

How will i print the username and password based on employee_id? please help me :(

Comment: **DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAIN TEXT!!!**  Use an SHA-512 hash

Comment: @dave: Do you need help with FPDF or with the database?

Comment: Will need a bit more information than that...

Comment: This is one of the worst questions ever

Comment: i need the help with FPDF not with database! i know how to queries in database but in FPDF im a newbie

Comment: You **should not** be doing this at all.

Comment: the employee table was just an example!! my question is how will i be able to print in PDF using FPDF the username and passsword based on employee_ID? PHP and MYSQL and FPDF is what i am using

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the best ways to accidentally passwords and embarrass your company.

## *Never* store passwords in plain text!

and *certainly* never print them out.

You should destroy your `password` column and replace it with an SHA-512 hash.

---

To answer the question:

```
SELECT Username FROM employee WHERE emplyee_id = @id
```

Comment: the employee table was just an example!! my question is how will i be able to print in PDF using FPDF the username and passsword based on employee_ID?

Comment: _You should not print passwords in a PDF!_!

Answer (score 0):

What are you using? T-SQL?

First of all NEVER store/print passwords in plain text. But..

```
SELECT username, password FROM table ORDER BY employee_id
```

Or if you want to select the username for each employee individually then

```
SELECT username, password FROM table WHERE employee_id = @id
```

Where @id is the employee id number of the employee you want the information about.